# Microservices configuration server

Tags: microservices

It's well understood that in a microservices architecture, configuration must be externalized.

Tools like zookeeper, etcd or consul are excellent options to store that configuration. However a new layer on top of those services is required in order to provide new functionalities that are fundamental in a configuration server. Ex. versioning; change history; "draft" / published configuration, etc...

I've found [spring config server](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config), which is an interesting project and addresses all these concerns using git for handling the above mentioned requirements. However, I'd like avoid using git due to additional required setup. ex. replication, etc...

Do you know any other options other then spring config server?

Answer (score 2):

Our findings have been the same - configuration must be externalized and the notion of "code as config" through the lessons learned from implementing time consuming Puppet/Chef systems.

We're building a microservices and API orchestration system at LunchBadger. We also uses git - but it's encapsulated into our system that we provide as a service, because we want configuration to be externalized AND dovetail into whatever CI/CD pipeline infrastructure you may have or are looking to adopt. We also provide visualization on top of microservices and APIs so that you can get an idea of the topology of your once monolithic app in the form of many microservices.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Microconfig.IO](https://microconfig.io) and it's Microconfig Server. It's deployed via docker and configured via 3 env vars. It still use git repo for config storage, but that's actually a proper way to go. As a bonus you get a powerful templating functionality designed explicitly to handle app configuration